# how to read javascript array in php

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying post a javascript array using jquery $.post method to php and use array values in mysql query.

```
$.post("test.php", { 'celvalues[]': celValues }});
```

where values for array celvalues is assigned.
So how to read this array in php?

Comment: Did you try `$_POST['celvalues']`?

Comment: It give notice: Undefined index: cellValues in............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`json_decode($_POST['cellValues'])`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in PHP.  Use this for your JavaScript:

```
$.post('test.php', {cellvalues: celValues});
```

Comment: It give notice: Undefined index cellValues in...Can I use code: $.post("test.php", { celvalues: celValues },function(data){
       alert (data);
   }); to test it.but this code doesn't work.

Comment: @tutor777, `print_r($_POST)` and see what you are posting.

Comment: It displays array values with index in alert box with same notice:Undefined index cellValues in...

Comment: @tutor777, I can't help you if you don't post the exact output from what I just suggested.

Comment: jquery:$.post("test.php", { celvalues: celValues },function(data){document.write(data);});   
test.php:echo json_decode($_POST['cellValues']);
         print_r($_POST);                              output:Notice: Undefined index: cellValues in C:\wamp\www\php_testbox\test.php on line 6
Array ( [celvalues] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 [2] => 2 [3] => 5 [4] => 3 [5] => 6 ) )

Comment: @tutor777, You are spelling `cellValues` two different ways.  Nothing more.  It looks to me like you already have your array though, so no need to decode it.

Comment: So how to store posted array into php array? I m trying following code:
foreach($_POST['celValues'] as $val)
         {
   $arr[i]=$val;
   $i++; 
   }